# Fixing deadlocks in messy code

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I'm modifying a bit of seriously complex code and I need to add my own synchronization on top of this.

However, the existing code has about a dozen, if not more, different locks, and my code needs to call some of its methods. I don't really know the order in which the locks are being obtained, nor can I really control it.

So, my question is, what would happen if I replaced all the different locks by a single lock?.Apart from sacrificing granularity, is there any other issue I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code?

Comment: No, it's like 3000+ lines. :-D It's not my code, mind you...

Comment: From what I understand, if you need atomicity on all the methods, you need to have a single lock, if you want fairness, such that each thread will be served by the processor in the order they seek the resource, you can take a look at the java.util.concurrent.Lock ( which guarantees fairness, but it comes with an overhead ). Please read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09238/index.html and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/ for better understanding of locks and happens-before ordering in java.

Comment: Having spent the last week wrist-deep in multi-threaded code that wasn't mine, I can tell you that it isn't going to be easy and you'll probably have to take the time to really grok this code. I would hesitate to blindly replace locks without understanding how the code currently works. Fortunately the JVM is pretty good at detecting deadlocks, so if you haven't already you should learn how to capture and read thread dumps. Finally, without having seen the code, I'll say that you should definitely prefer the tools in java.util.concurrent over any home-grown locking solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change all of the `synchronized` blocks (and methods), *and* all the other blocking structures, I think you should be fine -- worst case, your app degenerates to having serial execution. But if you only change some of them, you could get deadlock. Consider a scenario where two threads are each acquiring multiple locks:

```
Thread 1:
    synchronized A
        synchronized B

Thread 2:
    synchronized B
        synchronized C
```

There's no risk of deadlock here, but if you replace `A` and `C` (but not `B`) with the new, common lock, then you'll have:

```
Thread 1:
    synchronized L
        synchronized B

Thread 2:
    synchronized B
        synchronized L
```

... which is the classic deadlock case.

Consider another scenario, where the locks don't provide deadlock themselves, but instead deadlock a blocking class like a CountDownLatch:

```
Thread 1:
    synchronized A
        latch L.countDown()

Thread 2:
    synchronized B
        latch L.await()
```

In this case, changing both `synchronized` blocks to lock on a common lock won't cause deadlock between them, but will cause deadlock if thread 2 gets the lock first: it'll await the latch's countDown, which will never come because thread 1 is blocked at its `synchronized` entry point. This example applies to other blocking structures, too: semaphores, blocking queues, etc.

Comment: Good point re the countdown latches - if you replace the locks, you also have to ensure you release the lock whenever you wait on a common resource if this wasn't being done already.

Comment: Thanks @yshavit! I don't understand the last example, however. Latches are something new to me, so if I don't see latches in the code I shouldn't bother, should I? Or did you mean something more abstract by `latch`? Thanks!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore As @Alex pointed out, it's really any resource which can block. Many of the classes in `java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.locks` apply, but it could in principle be other resources (like one piece of code creating a file and another piece of code waiting for that file to exist).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any substitute for properly analysing the code. The reason it is horrible is probably because everyone else who has had to modify it has done exactly the same as you and baulked at a proper analysis.

It should be fairly simple to write some logging code that should clarify the locking. Once you can unpick the layers and have a clear picture it should be comparatively simple to replace the whole lot with one modern lock such as a `ReadWriteLock` or similar.

You may find it useful to take this opportunity to add some test code to exercise your logging in a controlled fashion. A very useful addition to any piece of complex code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly what would happen without seeing the code.
You might run into a deadlock issue if while inside one of the locks, it tries to grab another lock.  Also it could slow the application down while waiting to acquire a single lock vs multiple locks.

Comment: Well, my idea was that if I merge all the locks into one, it'd get rid of the dead-lock issue sacrificing granularity. I am wondering whether I'm right.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore if locking is the only sort of synchronization that's happening then you're probably right. Just understand that by sacrificing granularity, you might also be sacrificing performance and introducing opportunity for starvation.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm OK with possible performance issues, truth is, most of the methods take really, really small time (e.g. less than a few ms) and there's small chance for too many threads calling at the same time, but on the other hand, the complexity of the code is enourmous and yet I fail to see why did they introduced even more complexity using that many locks. Thanks a lot for confirming my thoughts.